# What are the SEC80 and SECD00 Android Wi-Fi capabilities?

Tags: wi-fi

I have been collecting Android `ScanResult.capabilities` for a while and have encountered some settings I can't find any description of.

`[ESS][SEC80][SECD00]` and `[WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS][SEC80][SECD00]`

These were on two different access points scanned by a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0.

What is `SEC80` and `SECD00`? They seem to be enabled together. Any link to an explanation for the two Wi-Fi capabilities will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question, but rather a pure Android question.

Comment: Yep, I still can't find anything. Have you tried the suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t/7019338#7019338 and used `AccessPointState.getScanResultSecurity`

Comment: I have come across that suggestion earlier, but the link is broken (or I don't know what to click).

Comment: I think I found your answer. They are capability flags: https://github.com/gopicsw/pdn-slatedroid-froyo/blob/9a33664a6f0bf7ead8688d13b6a517674cdee08d/froyo/external/wpa_supplicant_6/wpa_supplicant/wpa_gui-qt4/scanresults.cpp#L89

Comment: the flags reference this list: https://sourcecodebrowser.com/network-manager/0.8/_network_manager_8h.html#acb60dd58623392ab0183ec57117cbf64

Comment: so, SEC80 would be `NM_802_11_AP_SEC_GROUP_CCMP`

Comment: That was a wild ride in WPA specifications and Android source code, but this question really is an Android internal coding question mixed with a WiFi specification question, and not a security question. I'm glad the community (thanks @Adi) was able to solve this mystery.

Comment: How on earth were you able to dig that up? Very impressive! How did you? Will you move the question somewhere where I can give credit?

Comment: It actually wasn't me. As I say, I'm not sure where to migrate this to, but I'll try over at Android.SE.

Comment: I guess I'll wait for an answer by @Adi? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. Sorry for the confusion due to migration, but take a [tour] for a moment to understand the scope of this site, which focuses more on *end-users*. That said, this question *looks like* related to development due to API call and such (which usually is off-topic), but it seems you're interested in Android Wi-Fi capabilities in general (which might be okay, or off-topic due to Android-independent, but I personally can't make a call due to my little knowledge on this field).

Comment: Did Adi answer the question anywhere? I can't see the original post due to the migration, but it's weird if the answer is not migrated also...

Comment: Hi Andrew. It was on hold so it was not possible to add an answer. It was all handled in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure any forum wants to touch this question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! Several years ago I was thinking about extending some aspects of WPA and wanted to test using my phone. It seemed that you need to add these as flags, so that made me dive in the Android source code, specifically `wpa_supplicant`.

Then @schroeder posted a link to your question on a private chat room, and it instantly rang a bell. I went back to the [`wpa_supplicant` source code](https://github.com/gopicsw/pdn-slatedroid-froyo/blob/9a33664a6f0bf7ead8688d13b6a517674cdee08d/froyo/external/wpa_supplicant_6/wpa_supplicant/wpa_gui-qt4/scanresults.cpp#L89) and traced it back a bit until I found references for the flags. If you look at line 89 there, you can see that the scan results entries ordered in the same exact order they appear in scan results console, so from there you can see that they're "flags" and you can go back in the source code to where they're declared.

Anyway, these are called '**802.11 Access Point security flags**'. [Here's the reference list of the flags used in Android](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/network-manager/0.8/_network_manager_8h.html#acb60dd58623392ab0183ec57117cbf64). For instance, `[SEC80]` would be `NM_802_11_AP_SEC_GROUP_CCMP`. I'm not really sure what `[SECD00]`, but the [802.11-2012 specifications](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html) might give you some hints.